# longest possible chain from a collection of ordered pairs/ co-ordinates

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization

I have a bunch of ordered pairs x, y where 0 < x < y <= n (some given upper bound)

like S = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (3,4)]

I need to find the Length of the longest subset where all the numbers within the ordered pairs are unique.

Here that would be 2. eg: (1,4) (2,3)

I am writing code that deals with situations where n is in 100s and S contains thousands of ordered pairs. So looping through the possible combinations is too much computation. I am looking for some other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of the [*maximum independent set problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)#Maximum_independent_sets_and_maximum_cliques) (equivalently, maximum clique of the complement) in a graph with a node per ordered pair and an edge for each pair of ordered pairs that intersect.  You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether node $i$ is chosen.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_i x_i$ subject to a conflict constraint $x_i + x_j \le 1$ for each edge $\{i,j\}$.

As @Emil Jeřábek 3.0 observed, in the case of pairs, you can instead reformulate as a maximum matching problem in a graph with node set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and edge set $S$.  You can solve that problem via the [blossom algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm)  You can also solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether edge $\{i,j\}$ is chosen.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_{\{i,j\}\in S} y_{i,j}$ subject to a constraint $\sum_{\{i,j\}\in S: k\in\{i,j\}} y_{i,j} \le 1$ for each node $k$.

Comment: Based on the other comments, I’m not sure I read the question as intended.

Comment: I don't know what comments I missed, but as it stands this question is precisely maximum matching since the ordering of the pairs is unimportant.

Comment: @BenBarber (The comments are under my answer, now deleted.) Even though the OP says “ordered pairs”, they apparently treat them as unordered pairs, in particular, the pairs in any solution must be *disjoint*. Notice that in the specific example given in the question, there exists a 3-element matching $\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}$, whereas the OP says the optimal solution has size 2.

Comment: I think the "ordered pairs" in the question is the usual confusion that if you want to ignore order, you write the elements in canonical order.  It should have been {1,2} instead of (1,2).

Comment: Yup, I used the wrong term, it should be {1,2} as rob suggested